# setIntervall if checkbox is checked, JS

Tags: javascript

I have a Problem.
I want to do a function while my Checkbox is checked. If I unchecked it, the function shouldn't be done anymore till i check the box again.

My Code:

```
<Input type="Checkbox" id="autoPlay">Autoplay</Input>

<script type="text/JavaScript>//in the body
var checkBox = document.getElementById("autoPlay");
if(checkBox.checked == true){
setInterval(gallery("vor"), 3000);
}

</script>
```

I also tried to do it with a while-loop. But it doesn't work.

Comment: "Doesn't work". Please be more specific and prove a jsfiddle link so we can debugg it. I guess that your function gets executed even when you uncheck the input. This might be because you dont assign an event to the input field :)

Comment: you should add the click event in the checkbox, to trigger the function

Comment: @noa-dev Yeah sorry, I didn't knew how to say it. But it has already be solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bind a change event handler to the checkbox and based on the checked property initialize or stop interval.

```html
<Input type="Checkbox" id="autoPlay">Autoplay</Input>

<script>
  var checkBox = document.getElementById("autoPlay");
  var int;
  checkBox.addEventListener('change', function() { // bind change event handler
    if (int) clearInterval(int); // clear any previous interval
    if (this.checked) { // if checked then start the interval
      int = setInterval(function() {
        gallery("vor");
      }, 3000);
    }
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Yes. It's just a hidden `if` statement. Just because it's *possible* to abuse the `&&` operator that way doesn't mean it's a good idea. :-)

Comment: Not if `checked` is `true` twice in a row. Again, as I said, it seems unlikely that you'd get a `change` event when `checked` didn't really change, but...

Comment: @T.J.Crowder :  I got it now... :) Thanks

Comment: @T.J.Crowder :  but, is there any possibility for that ?

Comment: I wouldn't bet against it. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder : while firing change event using javascript, may it happen ?

Comment: That's an excellent example. But I wouldn't bet against some browser doing it in an odd situation either (particularly not the one from Redmond).

Comment: Yeah, saw you switched it back, cool. Probably for the best. :-)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111850/discussion-between-pranav-c-balan-and-t-j-crowder).

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<Input type="Checkbox" id="autoPlay" onclick="check()">Autoplay</Input>
```

JS:

```
function check()
{
    if (document.getElementById('autoPlay').checked) {
        //yourcode
    }
}
```